# php - Class 'Browscap' not found in

Tags: php

I'm using Browscap downloaded from Github.
So I have a _class.php

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . "/core/CORE.php";
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . "/core/Browscap.php";
// use phpbrowscap\Browscap;

class _class extends CORE {

//put your code here

public function __construct($mysql_setup = null) {
    parent::__construct($mysql_setup);

    $bc = new Browscap(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../cache"); //this is the error line
    $get_browser = $bc->getBrowser(null, true);
    $get_browser["HTTP_REFERER"] = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
    $get_browser["REQUEST_TIME"] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME"]);
    $this->dbCreateTable();

    $user = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . ";" . session_id();
    if ($this->insertUser($user) !== false) {
        $http_user_id = $this->dbLastInsertID();
        foreach ($get_browser as $k => $v) {
            if (($type_id = $this->getHttpUserTypeDB($k)) !== false) {
                $this->dbInsert("http_user_agent_infos", array("info" => $v, "http_user_agent_id" => $http_user_id, "http_user_agent_type_id" => $type_id));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My directory hierarchy is like this

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\test
         classes(folder)
               core(folder)
                       Browscap.php
                       CORE.php
               _class.php
               form.php
         cache(folder)
               browscap.ini
               cache.php
         php_browscap.ini
```

The error is

```
Fatal error</b>:  Class 'Browscap' not found in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\job6b\classes\_class.php</b> on line <b>28</b><br />
```

I'm not sure where I have my error...or did I put the path wrongly?

Thanks

Comment: I notice the line `use phpbrowscap\Browscap;` is commented out. Is the `Browscap` class declared with a namespace in the included file? If so, that's your problem - you either need the `use` line, or `$bc = new Browscap` should be `$bc = new phpbrowscap\Browscap`

Comment: @IMSoP Thanks, I didn't realize since I'm not the one who developed this (from previous developer). I just need the "use" line.

Comment: For future reference, you can [learn about namespaces in the PHP manual here](http://php.net/namespace). The simple summary is that the class name `Browscap` in this case is actually an abbreviation for `phpbrowscap\Browscap`. You can find out what namespace a class is in by opening up the file and looking for the `namespace` keyword.

Comment: hi @IMSoP yes, that file contains 'namespace' keyword. thanks for the info!